# Understanding Σ* and Σ in formal languages

Tags: automata, formal-languages, computability

If I have `Σ={a}` , what words does `Σ*` has ?

`Σ*= {a,aa,aaa,aaaa.....}` ?

Thanks

Comment: empty string should be included.

Comment: This presentation based on the book by Rosen might be useful 
http://www.cis.temple.edu/~latecki/Courses/CIS166-05/Lectures/ch11.1.ppt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your alphabet is `Σ={a}` then
`Σ*= {#, a,aa,aaa,aaaa.....}` means all the possible `n* a`, including the empty string `# (phi)`. Another way to produce that sequence is using grammars:

```
S -> S
S -> aS
S -> #
```

where `#` is the empty string.

Answer (score 2):

It has the empty string, which you didn't mention, it also contains sequences of a, of all lengths.

You can find more information at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star.

Answer (score 1):

The `*` in `Σ*` usually denotes *zero or many times*. So `Σ*` will have the empty string, and any combination of letters from the alphabet `Σ`.

(Since your alphabet only has `a` , then `Σ*` will have any combination of `a`s *and* the empty string.)

If your alphabet had more values i.e. `Σ = {a,b}` then you would have any combination of `a`s and `b`s *and* the empty string. i.e. `Σ* = {phi, a, b, aa, ab, ba, bb, bab, ...(etc)}`

Answer (score 0):

`Σ*` is the set of strings of any length that you can make by concatenating any number of symbols drawn from `Σ` (including none).

Here is one way to define `Σ*`:

Let `Σ^n` be the set of strings of length n over `Σ`.

Then Σ* = Σ^0 union Σ^1 union ...

`Σ^0 = {phi}` since phi is the only string of length `0`. Therefore phi is always in `Σ*` no matter what `Σ` is.